# Android - Encoding on write/read file

Tags: java, android, string, file, encoding

I have a String which contains 2 byte (16 bit) ASCII characters from encryption.
Then I write it to a file with this code:

```
String result = encrypt("text"); //some encryption method
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
fos.write(result.getBytes("ISO-8859-15"));
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

The problem is when I read the file, the string value is already different.
Below is the code which I use to read the file:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "ISO-8859-15"));
String line;
String txt = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) txt = txt + line;
```

I found that String txt is already different than String result. I even made a method to sum all the character's ASCII in the string, and found it different.
And I have no idea what's my mistake. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've encrypted it, you don't want to write it out as a string and apply an encoding.  Every encryption method I know of treats data as an array of bytes.  You need to do any character set converting before encryption, and after decryption.  In Java you shouldn't even be holding the post-encryption data as a string, it ought to be an array of bytes.

Also, there is no such thing as 16 bit ASCII.  ASCII is 8 bit.  You're using some sort of wide character data or 16 bit unicode, not ascii.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually 16 bit ASCII I mentioned earlier was like typecasting a **char** to **long**. And I work my whole encryption using **long** data type (since my encryption uses 256 bit key, while **byte** data type cannot handle that long). Then what should I do if my encryption is already done in **long** ?

Comment: First, I'm hoping that if you're writing your own encryption, its a learning exercise.  Rule #1 of encryption is don't write your own, unless you're an expert.  Anyway, encryption algorithms (at least all the ones I know of) work on arrays of bytes as input and output-  not strings.  Those bytes may have text strings in them, but the algorithm doesn't work at that level.  You should call .toByteArray on the string, encrypt that data, and use that as your cyphertext.  On decode you decode it, then turn that array into characters again.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter if I have to encrypt with **byte[]** or **String**, as long as the encryption works. But what should I do with the String ciphertext before writing it to the file? If the ciphertext must be **byte[]**, isn't String.getBytes() already solve the problem? But the reality, it isn't... I don't have any idea why.

Comment: you're right... encryption should not be done by using **String**... I was changing my file writing method to manually write using **byte[]** and it works! so does when I was reading the file, it has to be done not by reading per line, but reading it into **byte[]**... thanks btw!